# How to show preselected file to a file type input in angularjs?

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I want to apply required validation on file input type. In some cases 's3' file path is already in db so I have to show preselected file in these cases. Because if I don't preselect the file then it will give me "required validation error"; Even if it doesn't show me preselected but it shouldn't give me required validation error.
I have tried with ng-modal but its not working.

```
<input required onchange="angular.element(this).scope().uploadProfilepic(this.files)" type="file" />
```

Answer (score 0):

> Because if I don't preselect the file

It is not possible to "preselect" a `File` object at `<input type="file" />` element

Comment: Then how to apply required validation in this case.

Comment: @user3542450 You can use an `if..else` statement to check `path` of user selected file within `onchange` handler

Comment: would be  lot simpler using proper angular methodology and use `ng-if` for the whole file input if the data already exists. Using `onchange` in angular is terrible practice

Comment: @charlietfl ng-if also not working, ng-if just show-hide the file input field.

Comment: @user3542450 You can also utilize `.name` property of `File` object to get user selected file name https://jsfiddle.net/Lof7c8vz/

Comment: @user3542450 then use `ng-required` if you must have the field and use scope variable to set it. Note that `ng-if` does not hide it...it removes it. Whole issue sounds like an `XY problem`